# pe:blockUI how to disable fade effect?

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I am using the [Primefaces Extensions BlockUI](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/blockui/blockPage.jsf) component for global ajax events like this:

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('globalBlockUI').block({ fadeIn: 0 })" onsuccess="PF('globalBlockUI').unblock({ fadeOut: 0 })"/>

<pe:blockUI id="globalBlockUI" widgetVar="globalBlockUI"
            css ="{}"
            cssOverlay="{}">
...
</pe:blockUI>
```

I would like to disable the fade effect. Setting the {fadeIn: 0} option like in [JQuery](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#options) seems to be ignored.

How do I disable the fade effect?

Comment: Look at the  javascript source of ajaxStatus...

Comment: I beg your pardon, I dont see the connection between ajaxStatus and why the fade option is being ignored. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Sorry, commented the wrong way around... look at the javascript source of `pe:blockUI` (and try to override if that is the only option)

Comment: @Thomas just want to check if my solution below solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your page...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.blockUI.defaults.fadeIn = 0;
</script>
```

I have also created this ticket so those attributes get added as first class citizens on the component itself: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/594

**UPDATE:** I have committed a fix for the above GitHub ticket. So you will be able to do...

```
<pe:blockUI id="globalBlockUI" fadeIn="0" fadeOut="0"/>
```

Comment: Hi Melloware, thanx a lot for your fast reply. Setting the defaults seems to work for some places, but not for all. Im not sure why. Seems if there is a tartget=":something" set, then the defaults work. It seems not to work if the target property is left out as it is done in my initial example. I did not test your new version though. I will give feedback once I did that.

Comment: OK great.  Definitely let me know how it goes after you test the PFE SNAPSHOT build with the new properties in it.